# How to retrieve query string value from URL value stored in a variable?

Tags: php, query-string

$url = 'http://www.domain.com/file.php?dir=r&hl=100,200&ord=3&key=a+b+c';

If it were a url I could get value of `hl` by, say, `$_GET['hl']`. but how do I retrieve the same from $url string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/file.php?dir=r&hl=100,200&ord=3&key=a+b+c';
print "<pre>";

print $url;

$url_parsed = parse_url($url);
print_r($url_parsed);

parse_str($url_parsed['query'], $url_parts);
print_r($url_parts);

print "</pre>";
```

Produces this output:

```
http://www.domain.com/file.php?dir=r&hl=100,200&ord=3&key=a+b+cArray
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.domain.com
    [path] => /file.php
    [query] => dir=r&hl=100,200&ord=3&key=a+b+c
)
Array
(
    [dir] => r
    [hl] => 100,200
    [ord] => 3
    [key] => a b c
)
```

See [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

So the steps to get the **`h1`** value you want are:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/file.php?dir=r&hl=100,200&ord=3&key=a+b+c';
$url_parsed = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url_parsed['query'], $url_parts);
print $url_parts['h1'];
```

Answer (score 4):

With the [parse_url](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) functions.

```
$qs = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($qs, $values);
```

This gives for `$values`:

```
array(4) {
  ["dir"]=>
  string(1) "r"
  ["hl"]=>
  string(7) "100,200"
  ["ord"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["key"]=>
  string(5) "a b c"
}
```